# stdin read python from piped looping process

Tags: python, background-process

How can I  spawn or Popen a subprocess in python and process its output in realtime?
The subprocess prints output randomly depending on other system events.

This "example" hangs:

`$./print.sh | ./echo.py` hangs.

### `print.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]; do
echo 'A'
sleep 1
done
```

### `echo.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
  print line
```

Comment: update your question with os details.

Comment: @tuxuday It's obviously unix-like (Linux, Mac OS X), since he's using bash. Why do you need to know anything more to answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't hang. `echo`/the shell decides that, because it's writing to a pipe, it will perform I/O in a block-buffered rather than line-buffered mode. If you wait long enough, or remove the `sleep 1` from the shell script, you'll see that the output from `A` does come through.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Modify the subprocess's program so that it flushes its buffers when it's written enough output for the Python program to process.
2. Use pseudo-terminals (PTYs) instead of pipes. [`pexpect`](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) does that, hiding most of the complexity from you. It's not a drop-in replacement for `subprocess`, though.

Comment: The point is that I need to process output realtime. Also, in production I use a program I cannot control, i.e. flush its stdout. What I want to do is to spawn/Popen an inotifywait process to monitor if new files are written to a directory. If a new file is written, get realtime the output from inotify and process the just written file

Answer (score 0):

check whether this coding snippet works.

cat ech.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]; do
echo -n 'A'
sleep 1
done
```

cat in_read.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os

while True:
  print os.read(0,1)
```

Comment: Yes it does. I will test it in the production environment. thanks